# Make assets folder accessible in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, thumbnails, asset-pipeline, assets

I am using Rails 3.2.13.
Working on a product based application. I want to show Thumbnail of product as a link instead of a boring text.
A rake task is adding thumbnails to `app/assets/screenshots/*` every 5 minutes.
I want the application to access them whenever they are there without assets-precompile.
Do we have some way in rails to make the app/assets/images/screenshots/* to be accessible to controllers/views in Production mode.
It would be good if you advise me what are the drawbacks of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the screeshots, in your case, are expected to be large and dynamic. So, they should be considered as **data** instead of **asset**.

Data should not be put in "/assets" even you are able to.

The "/assets" directory is supposed to be under version control. Imagine your repository to be polluted by theses.

So, my suggestion is to **revise your rake task** to put them under /public directory directly. That's easier, more reasonable and use less system resource.

For data, you can have another task to protect them say uploading them to Amazon if you like, but that's another story.

Comment: And what if i want them to have security, like only admins can see 1.png, 2.png and 3.png and public can see 4.png, 5.png, 6.png

Comment: Okay, can I being a user see all the data inside public/screenshots/* or I can access it by name only...

Comment: @NishutoshSharma, even you put such things in /assets you'll face the same problem. For this specific question, my suggestion is to give images unique token names even in public. Admin can see the image names and public can't though they can access. That should be secure enough for most cases.

Comment: well that's what I am thinking to append a long string-fingerpring name to the thumbnails, but is there anyway a user can see or download all the data in a particular folder in /public..
like, i go to www.domain.com/public/screenshots and I see all the images, is it possible, if not then it is secure for me

Comment: @NishutoshSharma, that' about server setting. Normally servers don't allow directory reading, but you need to check it in your server.